# How do I display Chinese characters with R&OS pdf class in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, cjk

I'm using R&OS: pdf class to generate PDF in php projects.
Both cpdf and ezpdf class are of great help in creating PDFs. Except printing of Chinese characters.
I can enter and display Chinese characters on html web page and store in MySQL. But they appeared blocks in PDF.
Do you know how to tackle this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried internationalization with ezPdf, but can you try doing

```
iconv("<chinese encoding>", "UTF-8", "text")
```

and send that to ezPdf libraries instead of directly sending over the chinese text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest version of the R&OS pdf class for php to support unicode fonts.
Also make sure you have a working unicode font which includes chinese characters.

The only I know (which was working) is Arial Unicode from Microsoft. 
http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081

In the current version 0.11.7 font subsetting is not available which will include the 22mb font file into the pdf document.

The SVN trunk of R&OS pdf classes has an EXPERIMENTAL version (0.11.8) which supports font subset.

More details here: http://sourceforge.net/p/pdf-php/blog/2013/07/fonts-the-2nd/